# RSS Parser for Django

Tags: python, django, parsing, rss

Data from a site http://www.case-parts.com are necessary to me.
To obtain these data, I plan to use RSS. All catalog of goods is necessary to me, however in RSS (http://www.case-parts.com/catalog.html) I manage to receive information only about the last arrivals on a site. How to receive all catalog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django provides syndication as a part of the framework. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/)

Basically, You create a class and define the feed. (This example is from [django](http://djangoproject.com))

```
class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed):
    title = "Chicagocrime.org site news"
    link = "/sitenews/"
    description = "Updates on changes and additions to chicagocrime.org."

    def items(self):
        return NewsItem.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.description

    # item_link is only needed if NewsItem has no get_absolute_url method.
    def item_link(self, item):
        return reverse('news-item', args=[item.pk])
```